# IIS Permission issue

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2

Hi Having a major authentication issue, I'm a relative IIS NOOB who has read everything and nothing works.

Setup: I have 2 sites (one port 80 and 1 port 81). Both running of the same local HDD both inhering same permissions. The port 80 site works perfectly, the port 81 site works as http://localhost:81/ but not as http://192.168.1.1:81/.

More detail: If I test settings in 'Basic Settings' the Authentication works but the "Authorization" fails saying "Cannot verify access to path". If I add a "connect as" user the "Authorization" will be successful but the site will still not work?

I have tried:

1. Adding all the network/local/ect users but with no change. If I swap the path in the working port 80 site then same behaviour.
2. Deleting the the website and reset permission to the local path so same as port 80 site but still not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the advance setting for application pool? make it as Local System and see

Comment: Default IP address for localhost is 127.0.0.1. Have you tried to access the site as http://127.0.0.1:81/ ?

Comment: Site bindings are the key here as that tells IIS which requests this site wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel seriously stupid... It was my firewall

I needed to allow port 81 incoming and outgoing in my firewall policy settings.